# there's no valid distribution profile for target

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I don't see the distribution under target settings but it's visible under project settings.

My login name on the system is Mac User

1) I made a new request for request certificate

2) I downloaded the distribution certificate from portal and drag into my keychain, I verified the Mac User named private key is underneath the certificate

3)I made a distribution profile under portal and dragged into xcode.

it says cosign error the identity ipone Distribution doesn't match identity  in any profile

Comment: Yet another codesign error question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your bundle ID does not match?